# TKinter: Entry not using correct textvariable when iterating

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

I have a loop that constructs multiple sets of Entries with Buttons next to them so:

```
set 0: [Item0 Entry] [Item0 Edit Button]
.
.
.
set 1: [Item0 Entry] [Item0 Edit Button]
etc
```

During each iteration I create a variable

```
Item0Var = StringVar()
```

Which I then initialise through say

```
Item0Var.set("None")
```

I store the variable in an external dictionary

```
self.CurrentEquipSets[set_num].update(
            {"Item0" : Item0Var,...} )
```

The variable is then displayed in a disabled Entry

```
Item0Entry = Entry(self.Item0Frame,textvariable=self.CurrentEquipSets[set_num]["Item0"],state=DISABLED,width=EntryWidth)
```

The button is

```
Item0Edit = Button(self.Item0Frame,text="Edit",command = lambda EquipSet=set_num,Item="Item0": self.EditItem(EquipSet,Item))
```

The textvariable is stored externally in the dictionary self.CurrentEquipSets

The button calls

```
def EditItem(self,EquipSet,Item):
    self.CurrentEquipSets[EquipSet][Item].set("Something")
```

The result I am looking for, if I have 3 sets, from pressing the Edit button for set 0 is:

```
set 0: Item0Entry ["Something"]
set 1: Item0Entry ["None"] 
set 3: Item0Entry ["None"]
```

But instead I get

```
set 0: Item0Entry ["None"]
set 1: Item0Entry ["None"] 
set 3: Item0Entry ["Something"]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please create a proper [mcve]. Making us figure out how to stitch all those little blocks of code isn’t a good way to get people to answer.

Comment: Sorry, it's quite a lot of code, but I guess I could have made a closer approximation of the full code!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out [{}]*listlength does not work for initating a list of dictionaries, the problem is solved!